# Removing the 3 key buffer

Tags: keyboard

I'm having this problem with my keyboard. Anytime I play Guitar Hero III and you're supposed to press three keys together (E, R & T) they do not work but all other three key combinations work?

 How do I remove this buffer?

Comment: I actually just tried it here on my keyboard and you're right, it only posts 2 keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a physical limitation of your keyboard.  Depending on how the switch matrix is setup in your keyboard some key combinations can't be detected.

Wikipedia knows all: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_%28key%29

Comment: This is almost certainly the problem and it's a physical limitation.  All I can say is 'Buy a Das Keyboard!'